# Liubre calc wrong date format

Tags: libreoffice

The date format I have looks currently like this 15/4/2013 which is wrong. Is there a simple way to correct it to 2013/04/15?

Comment: YYYY/MM/DD? IMO, if you're that close to ISO-8601, just use ISO-8601: YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I see I should learn markdown editing. where should I start?

Comment: Here: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the cell with the 15/4/2013 date entry.  Navigate to Format - Cells - Date.  Presumably, the "Format code" is displaying DD/MM/YYYY.  Change this format code to YYYY/MM/DD and press OK.  The subject cell should now display 2013/04/15.

Note that you could use the built-in format 1999-12-31 (Format code YYYY-MM-DD) if the slight difference in the display (hyphens rather than forward slashes) is acceptable.

Comment: I tried format cell but keeps the date the same. When I export as csv the file still shows the wrong date format which throws my data out.

Comment: What category, format, and format code are displayed in the Format Cells dialogue box for your unmodified date?  What variable type does the cell contain?  If I enter 15/4/2013 into a cell, the format shows as General - Number, but a test for a numeric value (ISNUMBER) shows as False.  The entry is actually text (ISTEXT=True).  However, if I enter 15-Apr-2013, the format shows as date (YYYY-MM-DD) by default.  Note that this uses the standard (ISO) date format.  So, I suspect that Calc is confused by the data that you have entered.  It probably doesn't see it as a date.